# call javascript function on asp dropdown list change

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```js
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ddl(id) {
      //          var id = document.getElementById('<%=DDLquestionType.ClientID%>').value;
                if (id == "Open") {
                    AmericanAnswer.style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('Answer1_Btn').style.visibility = false;
                    
                }
                alert(id);
            }
        </script>
```

```html
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLquestionType" CssClass="ddlQuestionType box"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" onchange="ddl(this)" >
                    <asp:ListItem Text="American" Value="American"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Open" Value="Open"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes/No" Value="YesNo"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Numerical" Value="Numerical"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

I have this java script function:

Which I try to call on drop down list selection change

It doesn't work. 
I also tried
    onchange="javascript:ddl()" and function without parameters, 
    ononchange="javascript:ddl(this);", 
    ononchange="javascript:ddl(this.value);", 
and many others.
I'm new to java script, any links with explanations also will be highly appreciated

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code. That's like going to a car repair shop with a photo of your car. Post your code.

Comment: @Tomalak Just copy-paste or there is better way to do it?

Comment: When you edit your question, you should see a yellow box with tips how to use the editor. Among other things it describes how to post code.

Comment: The `{}` control of the editor formats the selected text as code, indenting it with 4 spaces on each line (you can indent it manually if you prefer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dosent need to pass this parameter or id, you just call the function and onchange() event call the function.
in javascript use id of your dropdown list to get the value of dropdown list.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function processchange(value)
{
  if(ddl.value=="American")
    // your code
}
</script>

<dropdownlist id="ddl" onchange="processchange()" >
  //enter your dropdown items
  
  </dropdownlist>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you pass `this` as a parameter, you pass the DropDownList itself to the Javascript function. Therefore, you don't need to use the `id` to retrieve the control. You can get the value of the selected item with the `value` property, and you can access the items with the `options` array.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" onchange="processChange(this);" ... >

function processChange(ddl) {
    if (ddl.value == 'Open') {
        var americanItem = ddl.options[0];
        ...
    }
}
```

Since you have set `AutoPostBack="true"` for the DropDownList, some of the changes that you make in your Javascript function may be lost after the postback. You can try with `AutoPostBack="false"` to see the difference.